# What is a good Docker base image for Perl software development?

Tags: linux, perl

I'm developing a package using Perl and a lot of dependencies that I manage to install via cpanm. I'd like to distribute the software *also* as a Docker container.

I'd like to have some hints on which perl/cpanm powered base image to use, as I found several "cpanm" labeled distributions and would like one that is:

- Very Perl 5 and CPANM friendly
- Reliable
- Minimal but not barebone (a simple package manager to install external stuff like "wget" is appreciated)

Possibility to easily choose which Perl version to have is a plus.

Many thanks!

Comment: Is there anything missing from Perl's official image? https://hub.docker.com/_/perl/

Comment: I was looking from comments from developers that used it for a while. Not impressed by the base Dockerfile but if you think is a good start I’ll try it more

Comment: I've generally found the official base images a good place to start, although there's often a lot included which you might not want later on in a production environment where image size really matters (at that point I'd usually create a custom Alpine image with only the required parts).